# java.io.FileNotFoundException(Access denied) Error?But Files are getting Stored

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am getting an error HTTP Status 500 - java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\sam\IMAGES (Access is denied) while saving an image in the file 'IMAGES'.I tried all the things like changing the permission of the file and tried to save it in different folder.The strange thing is that my images are actually getting stored in the file which i mentioned above.But why still its shows the error?? how to resolve this error?Tomcat is under the ownership of user.

```
My Code:
MySampleUpload.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="FileUploadServlet" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="btn btn-success btn-file">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
             Browse
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name='submit'>submit</button>`
    </form>
</body>
</html>

FileUploadServlet.java



import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FileUploadServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/FileUploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,    // 10 MB 
maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,       // 50 MB
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)       // 100 MB
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    private static final String UPLOAD_DIR="IMAGES";
    public FileUploadServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //gets absolute path of the web application
        //String applicationPath=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        //construct path of the directory to save the uploaded file
        String UploadFilePath="C:/sam"+File.separator+UPLOAD_DIR;
        //creates the file directory if it doesn't exist
        File FileSaveDir=new File(UploadFilePath);

    if(!FileSaveDir.exists())
        {
            FileSaveDir.mkdirs();
        }

        System.out.println("Upload file Diiirectory"+FileSaveDir.getAbsolutePath());
        String fileName=null;
        //get all parts from request and write it to the file on the server
        for(Part part:request.getParts())
        {
            fileName=getFileName(part);

            part.write(UploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);

        }
        System.out.println("File Uploaded successfully");
        request.setAttribute("message",fileName+"file uploaded successfully");

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    private String getFileName(Part part)
    {
    String ContentDisp=part.getHeader("Content-Disposition");
    System.out.println("content-disposition-header"+ContentDisp);
    String[] tokens = ContentDisp.split(";");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);

        }
    } return "";
    }}
```

Comment: And all that without any code?

Comment: perhaps adding a few code lines and showing where exactly the error is shown would help, as well as mention which user is tomcat running under at and what are the directory's permissions

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? How many parts are there in the request when you upload a single file? Do all these parts contain a `fileName`? What do you think will happen if `getFileName` returns an empty string?

Comment: your part object iterated 2 times , from that 1st time it get file name and 2nd time it is null.so check filename inside part for null.

Comment: Thank you for answering ...now its working @JChrist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your part object iterated 2 times , from that 1st time it get file name and 2nd time it is null.so check filename inside part for null.
Replace This Part.

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            fileName = getFileName(part);
            if (fileName != null && !"".equals(fileName)) {
                part.write(UploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank u,will try this one:)

Comment: Thank you soo much...it worked well...:) @Sanjay Patel

Comment: But i don't get the thing which you said..how its iterated two times..i am beginner in java..if you explain a little more it will be easy to understand.

Comment: is it with the getFileName() method where it return" "??

Comment: actually Part object gives two component. 1) file component 2)submit component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code also , where form component and file component are separated.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                // ... (do your job here)
            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                // ... (do your job here)
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time,now i understand well..:)